# Nested #defines to build a URL?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I want to have some URLs as hardcoded `#define`s. Some of them require usernames. I am looking for the possibility to do the following:

```
#define kUserName John
#define kUserInfoURL(USERNAME) [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a.com/USERNAME"]
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, it's called *stringification* ([see link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification)):

`#define kUserInfoURL(USERNAME) [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a.com/" #USERNAME]`

However, this is gonna work with hardcoded usernames only. If you pass a variable, you'll get the name of the variable, not its contents.
Why don't you create a method or function which will return you the same?

Example:

```
#define kBaseUrl @"http://a.com"

- (NSURL*)createUrlForUser:(NSString*)username {
   NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", kBaseUrl, username];
   return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
}
```